# How do I get VS code to show me my compiler options?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile a C++ piece of code using VS Code, but when I click the terminal, I don't get any compiler task options.

I downloaded

`MinGW-x64`

and saved to my windows path correctly

`C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`

When I check the compiler version in the terminal, it shows

`MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably looking for the magical C/C++ language.  You should choose C or C++.  For example, use `gcc` for the C language and `g++` for the C++ language.  They are distinct languages, for example, C++ has `delete[]` and C doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run my C++ program by also installing an extension called
`code runner` and using the shortcuts provided.